# How to send an email using PHP 5?

Tags: php

I want to send email with php please how to do

Comment: Thank :) i will learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this documentation for a complete guide 
[PHP.net: Mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Thank i will learn